# Matching a letter from any language spoken

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, letters

.NET, Java, Perl, PHP, Python3(?) all support PCRE's `\p{L}` regex that matches unicode character representing a letter, but there is no such a shortcut in JavaScript (as far as I know)... I'm working on a library focused on string manipulations, and I badly need the equivalent for JavaScript. So far I've got the **1172 characters long regex** bellow, built in a rather clunky way. I would appreciate if someone could confirm/deny if got it right, **or better, how to make it more general and accurate**. Here's the way I've got it, top to bottom:

```
//
// JavaScript synonym for (.NET/Java/Perl/PCRE)'s `\p{L}` regexp.


// get range of characters
function crange (a, z) {

  var rng = [];

  if (a <= z) {

    for (

      var cc = a.charCodeAt(0) - 1,
        stop = z.charCodeAt(0),
        fromcc = String.fromCharCode;

      ++cc <= stop;

      rng.push(fromcc(cc))

    );

  }

  return rng;
}

// maps a list to another 2D-list 
// containing arrays with successive integers in it
Array.prototype.intranges = function () {

  for (

    var it = 0,
      // filter unique and numericaly sorted 
      // list of integers from given array
      self = this.filter(_intranges).sort(_nsort),
      len = self.length,
      res = [],
      buff,
      curr;

    buff = curr = self[it], it < len;

    // ignore update

  ) {

    // increment while integers are successive
    while (self[(++it)] == (++buff));

    // save
    res.push(
      (self[(self.indexOf(curr) + 1)] == self[it]) ?
      [curr] : [curr, self[(it - 1)]]
    );

  }

  return res;
};


var letter_regex =

  // get all characters < 0xffff;
  crange('\u0000', '\uffff')

  // create [(int) codePoint, (char) character] pairs
  .map(function (c, i) {
    return [i, c];
  })

  // this one is tricky...
  //   what holds true for a character 
  //   that is regular letter, 
  //   not punctuation, whitespace, number, 
  //   or any other (fancy) unicode symbol?
  // 
  // I'm sure this part can be improved.
  // It checks if a character has it's
  // lower/upper-case version, 
  // assuming it's true for letters only...
  .filter(function (pair) {
    var p1 = pair[1];
    return p1.toUpperCase() != p1.toLowerCase();
  })

  // fetch those code-points 
  .map(function (pair) {
    return pair[0];
  })

  // build integer subranges out of them
  .intranges()

  // build a string out of it 
  // that can be used by `RegExp`
  .map(function (ccrange) {
    return ccrange.map(function (cc) {
      var c = cc.toString(16);
      return (cc <= 0xff) ? ('\\x' + pad02(c)) : ('\\u' + pad04(c));
    }).join('-');
  })
  .join('');

//
//
// and it generated this (10ft) long string:
//
// letter_regex = '\x41-\x5A\x61-\x7A\xB5\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xDE\xE0-\xF6\xF8-\u0137\u0139-\u0148\u014A-\u018C\u018E-\u019A\u019C-\u01A9\u01AC-\u01B9\u01BC-\u01BD\u01BF\u01C4-\u01EF\u01F1-\u0220\u0222-\u0233\u023A-\u0254\u0256-\u0257\u0259\u025B\u0260\u0263\u0265-\u0266\u0268-\u0269\u026B\u026F\u0271-\u0272\u0275\u027D\u0280\u0283\u0288-\u028C\u0292\u0345\u0370-\u0373\u0376-\u0377\u037B-\u037D\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u038F\u0391-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03AF\u03B1-\u03D1\u03D5-\u03F2\u03F4-\u03F5\u03F7-\u03FB\u03FD-\u0481\u048A-\u0527\u0531-\u0556\u0561-\u0586\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u1D79\u1D7D\u1E00-\u1E95\u1E9B\u1E9E\u1EA0-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F51\u1F53\u1F55\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB1\u1FB3\u1FB8-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC3\u1FC8-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD1\u1FD8-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FE1\u1FE5\u1FE8-\u1FEC\u1FF3\u1FF8-\u1FFC\u2126\u212A-\u212B\u2132\u214E\u2160-\u217F\u2183-\u2184\u24B6-\u24E9\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2C70\u2C72-\u2C73\u2C75-\u2C76\u2C7E-\u2CE3\u2CEB-\u2CEE\u2CF2-\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\uA640-\uA66D\uA680-\uA697\uA722-\uA72F\uA732-\uA76F\uA779-\uA787\uA78B-\uA78D\uA790-\uA793\uA7A0-\uA7AA\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A';
//
//



function pad02 (c) {
  return (Array(3).slice(c.length).join('0') + c).toUpperCase();
}

function pad04 (c) {
  return (Array(5).slice(c.length).join('0') + c).toUpperCase();
}

// filter out unique integers
function _intranges (node, pos, self) {
  return _isint(node) && (pos <= self.indexOf(node));
}

function _isint (n) {
  return (n | 0) === n;
}

function _nsort (n1, n2) {
  return n1 - n2;
}
// /eof
```

Comment: Take a look at http://xregexp.com/

Comment: https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/master/xregexp-all.js#L3460

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript + Unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode)

Comment: Since JavaScript has no built-in tool like `\p{L}`, you need a complicated regexp (or something even more complicated), either as coded by you or as a library routine written by someone else. The approach in the code in the question looks like a nice trick but does not actually work: most writing systems do not distinguish between upper and lower case at all.

Comment: **@Jukka K. Korpela**: yeah the task is rather complicated. But I think I've found the tool [unibookl@unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org/unibook/help/unibook.htm) to do it for me. Handy app, it lets you to browse and pick characters using all sorts of criteria and export them in plain `.lst` (txt) file. And the XRegExp looks promising, 'git-cloned' it already, and it has bunch of stuff I was looking for. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

I think I have the regex equiv. for `\p{L}`, I've used [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html) app to generate it. It covers 48k+ letter characters in `{Ll, Lm, Lo, Lt, Lu}` sets:

```
// JavaScript unicode letter regex: (4185 characters)
letter_regex = /[\x41-\x5A\x61-\x7A\xAA\xB5\xBA\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u0527\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0620-\u064A\u066E\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5\u06E6\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07CA-\u07EA\u07F4\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u0815\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08A0\u08A2-\u08AC\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0977\u0979-\u097F\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09F0\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32\u0A33\u0A35\u0A36\u0A38\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E\u0B9F\u0BA3\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C33\u0C35-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58\u0C59\u0C60\u0C61\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0\u0CE1\u0CF1\u0CF2\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D60\u0D61\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E81\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F4\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191C\u1950-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19C1-\u19C7\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1AA7\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE\u1BAF\u1BBA-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C4D-\u1C4F\u1C5A-\u1C7D\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF1\u1CF5\u1CF6\u1D00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2183\u2184\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CEE\u2CF2\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2E2F\u3005\u3006\u3031-\u3035\u303B\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FCC\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA61F\uA62A\uA62B\uA640-\uA66E\uA67F-\uA697\uA6A0-\uA6E5\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA78E\uA790-\uA793\uA7A0-\uA7AA\uA7F8-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA90A-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uA9CF\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA80-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEA\uAAF2-\uAAF4\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uABC0-\uABE2\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40\uFB41\uFB43\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]/;
//
```

I've posted the **version that includes code points `> 0xffff`** and characters it matches [here](http://nikolavukovic.herokuapp.com/_tmp/rletter.txt), (it's to much text to dump in single SO post).

Answer (score 0):

The below javascript solution catch the most common cases:

```
function(control) {
    // copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577220/matching-a-letter-from-any-language-spoken
    const isControlValid = control.value.match(/^[\x41-\x5A\x61-\x7A\xAA\xB5\xBA\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u0527\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0620-\u064A\u066E\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5\u06E6\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07CA-\u07EA\u07F4\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u0815\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08A0\u08A2-\u08AC\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0977\u0979-\u097F\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09F0\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32\u0A33\u0A35\u0A36\u0A38\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E\u0B9F\u0BA3\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C33\u0C35-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58\u0C59\u0C60\u0C61\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0\u0CE1\u0CF1\u0CF2\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D60\u0D61\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E81\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F4\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191C\u1950-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19C1-\u19C7\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1AA7\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE\u1BAF\u1BBA-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C4D-\u1C4F\u1C5A-\u1C7D\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF1\u1CF5\u1CF6\u1D00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2183\u2184\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CEE\u2CF2\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2E2F\u3005\u3006\u3031-\u3035\u303B\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FCC\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA61F\uA62A\uA62B\uA640-\uA66E\uA67F-\uA697\uA6A0-\uA6E5\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA78E\uA790-\uA793\uA7A0-\uA7AA\uA7F8-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA90A-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uA9CF\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA80-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEA\uAAF2-\uAAF4\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uABC0-\uABE2\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40\uFB41\uFB43\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC,'-.\s]+$/g);

    // (([^\x00-\x7F]+|[\w]+)?[.|\-|'|\s]{2,}([^\x00-\x7F]+|[\w]+)?)+ Validate cases like "asfagas--awgawg", "awfawf....asawgaw"
    // ([^\x00-\x7F]+|[\w]+)?[\-|\s]{1}$ Validate cases like "awfwafaw ", "awfwafaw-"
    // ^[\-|\s]{1}([^\x00-\x7F]+|[\w]+)?$ Validate cases like " awfwafaw ", "-awfwafaw"
    const hasErrorCombinations = control.value.match(/(([^\x00-\x7F]+|[\w]+)?[.\s\-']{4,}|[.\-']{3,}|[.]{2,}|[\-]{2,}|[']{2,}|[\s]{2,}([^\x00-\x7F]+|[\w]+)?)+|([^\x00-\x7F]+|[\w]+)?[\-|\s]{1}$|^[\-|\s]{1}([^\x00-\x7F]+|[\w]+)?$|^[\s]+|[\s]$/g);

    const hasAdditionalSymbolsCheckErrors = control.value.match(/[()+*]+/g);

    return isControlValid && !hasErrorCombinations && !hasAdditionalSymbolsCheckErrors;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.