# JS : Test if string contains any unicode capital

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

Do you know if there is a js regular expression that would catch any possibly unicode capital letter. Of course [A-Z] works but there are thousand of alternate capitals.
Thanks in advance for the hints.

Comment: unfortunately there seems to be no shortcut solution for javascript's regex engine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577220/matching-a-letter-from-any-language-spoken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only Unicode support in JavaScript regex (at least ecmascript 5 and below) is matching specific code points of the form `\uFFFF`. You can use those in ranges in character classes.  (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes))

This of course, makes your task difficult. But I **did** find an [online utility](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/js/regex#) that says it:

> Compiles character ranges suitable for use in JavaScript, using the
>   cset library.

Selecting "uppercase letter", then, produces this regex:

`[A-ZÀ-ÖØ-ÞĀĂĄĆĈĊČĎĐĒĔĖĘĚĜĞĠĢĤĦĨĪĬĮİĲĴĶĹĻĽĿŁŃŅŇŊŌŎŐŒŔŖŘŚŜŞŠŢŤŦŨŪŬŮŰŲŴŶŸ-ŹŻŽƁ-ƂƄƆ-ƇƉ-ƋƎ-ƑƓ-ƔƖ-ƘƜ-ƝƟ-ƠƢƤƦ-ƧƩƬƮ-ƯƱ-ƳƵƷ-ƸƼǄǇǊǍǏǑǓǕǗǙǛǞǠǢǤǦǨǪǬǮǱǴǶ-ǸǺǼǾȀȂȄȆȈȊȌȎȐȒȔȖȘȚȜȞȠȢȤȦȨȪȬȮȰȲȺ-ȻȽ-ȾɁɃ-ɆɈɊɌɎͰͲͶΆΈ-ΊΌΎ-ΏΑ-ΡΣ-ΫϏϒ-ϔϘϚϜϞϠϢϤϦϨϪϬϮϴϷϹ-ϺϽ-ЯѠѢѤѦѨѪѬѮѰѲѴѶѸѺѼѾҀҊҌҎҐҒҔҖҘҚҜҞҠҢҤҦҨҪҬҮҰҲҴҶҸҺҼҾӀ-ӁӃӅӇӉӋӍӐӒӔӖӘӚӜӞӠӢӤӦӨӪӬӮӰӲӴӶӸӺӼӾԀԂԄԆԈԊԌԎԐԒԔԖԘԚԜԞԠԢԱ-ՖႠ-ჅḀḂḄḆḈḊḌḎḐḒḔḖḘḚḜḞḠḢḤḦḨḪḬḮḰḲḴḶḸḺḼḾṀṂṄṆṈṊṌṎṐṒṔṖṘṚṜṞṠṢṤṦṨṪṬṮṰṲṴṶṸṺṼṾẀẂẄẆẈẊẌẎẐẒẔẞẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼẾỀỂỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪỬỮỰỲỴỶỸỺỼỾἈ-ἏἘ-ἝἨ-ἯἸ-ἿὈ-ὍὙὛὝὟὨ-ὯᾸ-ΆῈ-ΉῘ-ΊῨ-ῬῸ-Ώℂℇℋ-ℍℐ-ℒℕℙ-ℝℤΩℨK-ℭℰ-ℳℾ-ℿⅅↃⰀ-ⰮⱠⱢ-ⱤⱧⱩⱫⱭ-ⱯⱲⱵⲀⲂⲄⲆⲈⲊⲌⲎⲐⲒⲔⲖⲘⲚⲜⲞⲠⲢⲤⲦⲨⲪⲬⲮⲰⲲⲴⲶⲸⲺⲼⲾⳀⳂⳄⳆⳈⳊⳌⳎⳐⳒⳔⳖⳘⳚⳜⳞⳠⳢꙀꙂꙄꙆꙈꙊꙌꙎꙐꙒꙔꙖꙘꙚꙜꙞꙢꙤꙦꙨꙪꙬꚀꚂꚄꚆꚈꚊꚌꚎꚐꚒꚔꚖꜢꜤꜦꜨꜪꜬꜮꜲꜴꜶꜸꜺꜼꜾꝀꝂꝄꝆꝈꝊꝌꝎꝐꝒꝔꝖꝘꝚꝜꝞꝠꝢꝤꝦꝨꝪꝬꝮꝹꝻꝽ-ꝾꞀꞂꞄꞆꞋＡ-Ｚ]|\ud801[\udc00-\udc27]|\ud835[\udc00-\udc19\udc34-\udc4d\udc68-\udc81\udc9c\udc9e-\udc9f\udca2\udca5-\udca6\udca9-\udcac\udcae-\udcb5\udcd0-\udce9\udd04-\udd05\udd07-\udd0a\udd0d-\udd14\udd16-\udd1c\udd38-\udd39\udd3b-\udd3e\udd40-\udd44\udd46\udd4a-\udd50\udd6c-\udd85\udda0-\uddb9\uddd4-\udded\ude08-\ude21\ude3c-\ude55\ude70-\ude89\udea8-\udec0\udee2-\udefa\udf1c-\udf34\udf56-\udf6e\udf90-\udfa8\udfca]`

I've also read (but not used personally) that the [XRegExp javascript library](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) is good and would allow you to use `\p{Lu}`.

Comment: I couldn't get XRegExp to work as my project is not about web but ExtendScript aka Javascript for Adobe. But your first proposal seems to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link containing all Unicode capital letters. This is based on the GREP engine of Adobe InDesign CC2015, searching for the posix expression [[:upper:]]:

http://www.id-extras.com/uploads/AllUnicodeCapitals.html

Answer (score 0):

With any JavaScript environment supporting the ECMAScript2018+ standard, you can use

```
/\p{Lu}/u
```

to test if a string contains any Unicode uppercase letter.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
console.log(/\p{Lu}/u.test('... Yes!'));
console.log(/\p{Lu}/u.test('Łąka'));
console.log(/\p{Lu}/u.test('и Витя с ними'));
console.log(/\p{Lu}/u.test('nonono'));
```